# Jenkins query failed with exception'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8080 '

Tags: jenkins, tfs, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, tfvc

As the stated title I ran into a problem when trying to hook TFS to Jenkins in order to trigger build automatically when code is committed to the server.
[Here's the detailed picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSvMg.png).

FYI: I setup Jenkins on my localhost:8080 as default, my project I use on TFS also coded on local machine and use local DB (no idea if that's the problem). Project built successfully on Jenkins.

Please help me fix this problem and explain details if possible, since I'm new to Jenkins as well as CI/CD. Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Use IP address instead of *localhost* in Jenkins base URL.
2. Make sure you have projects configured in Jenkins.

https://www.visualstudio.com/get-started/integrate/integrating-with-service-hooks-vs

Comment: I try that but problems still occured, are there any other ways @Cece?

Comment: Is the Jenkins service running?

Comment: Everything running just fine. Is it necessary to install Jenkins on a different machine from my application? It's kinda hard since I only have one.

Comment: I don't think application will affect the service hook. Please try to logon your TFS Application Tier machine, and access Jenkins base URL http://IPaddress:8080/ to see whether you can access or not.